# Formatting an output to make a variable bold

Tags: excel, vba

I want to make the variable and units printed in bold. I realize this can be done by putting them into separate cells, but this could leave empty space. I was wondering if there was a way to do this within the same cell. Here is the code:

```
Cells(18 + Bound, 6) = "Total WP = " & TOTWP1 & "lbs."
```

So here I would want TOTWP1 and lbs to be printed in bold. Whatever I try just makes the entire cell bold. Any help is appreciated

Comment: `Cells(18 + Bound, 6).Characters(12).Font.Bold = True` after the line above.

Comment: You could do it manually (with text in a single cell) with the macro recorder turned on and then look at the resulting code.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this for several different fields and created a sub for it:

```
  Sub paintCell(txt as string, cll as range)
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim charNr As Integer
  Dim beginBold As Integer
  Dim countBold As Integer
  Dim sanitized As String

  charNr = 1
  sanitized = Replace(Replace(Replace(txt, "[", ""), "]", ""), "^", "")
  cll.Value2 = sanitized
  For i = 1 To Len(txt)
    Select Case Mid(txt, i, 1)
    Case "["
      beginBold = charNr
    Case "]"
      countBold = charNr - beginBold
      With .Characters(beginBold, countBold).Font
        .bold = true
      End With
    Case "^"
      .Characters(charNr, 1).Font.Superscript = True
    Case Else
      charNr = charNr + 1
    End Select
  Next i
  End Sub
```

Now you can create your strings like this:

```
 st="Total WP = [" & TOTWP1 & "]lbs."
```

and write them to the cell:

```
paintCell st, Cells(18 + Bound, 6)
```

As you can see, I also needed superscripts for footnotes: just add them with a ^before it:

```
 st="This is a reference^1"
```